# MX Linux установлено 2 python

Tags: python, linux, mxlinux

Недавно установил mx linux (полный новичок) и там установлено 2 python, так и должно быть? Если нет то как удалить python-2.x? и обновить python-3.x?

Comment: Советую поставить дистрибутив, который не предустанавливает ненужный софт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хочу дополнить ответ Spatz.

Действительно, системный питон нужен и удалять его опасно.
Но если все же нужно использовать версию, которая не поддерживается дистрибутивом, или нужно использовать несколько версий, скажем, 3-го питона паралельно, то есть такая программа [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

Она позволяет параллельно установить несколько версий питона и переключаться между ними (системный питон также трактуется, как одна из доступных версий). Так же `pyenv` позволяет указать конкретную версию (или virtualenv) для отдельной директории или сессии shell. Т.е. например, можно указать, глобально использовать одну версию, в папке проекта X - другую, а в конкретной сессии еще одну.

Важно, что при этом все версии установлены отдельно от системного питона и никак с ним не конфликтуют.

Answer (score 2):

```
там установлено 2 python, так и должно быть?
```

Да, это определено политикой дистрибутива Debian на базе которого собран MX Linux. Команда `python` запускает версию 2.x, а команда `python3` версию 3.x.

```
как удалить python-2.x?
```

Не пытайтесь удалить python-2.x или изменить умолчания с помощью `update-alternatives` - это нарушит работоспособность некоторых системных пакетов.

```
как обновить python-3.x?
```

Обновлять python-3.x рекомендуется исключительно средствами самого linux-дистрибутива, т.к. с ним в комплекте идут многочисленные бинарные модули, скомпилированные с оптимальными установками для данной системы. Не стоит стремиться установить самую последнюю версию, только потому что это "круто" - сначала спросите себя: ради какой новой функцинальности я хочу это сделать?